# Should Start-Process and Console Call be treated as the same thing?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question [Pass PowerShell variables to Docker commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599026) has been closed as a duplicate.
The question is about how to pass variable parameters to a Linux Docker image from a Windows console and I explicitly ask for a solution not using  `Start-Process` (not convenient for console).

In the supposed duplicate [Powershell Call MSI with Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223031/powershell-call-msi-with-arguments), the OP asks explicitly to fix a problem with running "many installers one after the other" with `Start-Process`.
The question is "implicitly" closed as the OP adds the edit

> EDIT: Nevermind, I figured it out.
>   (Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList  ...

*The fact that the solution working there does not fit my case should be already enough evidence that my question is not an actual  duplicate.*

Note that, since the question is not formally closed, I could **start a bounty** and ask for further answers. But what for? The current solution fits perfectly what the OP asks and needs (being MSIs GUI apps). 
People would keep posting possibly more interesting GUI approaches still not fitting my console case.

Despite the OP poses a Start-Process challenge, a member suggests: "Don't bother with Start-Process ... Use the call operator and splatting instead". Again this solution does not work for me because my case *is different*.  I also edited my question with parameter splatting to show this. The same member proposing this alternative approach considers my question a duplicate. Therefore I wonder

**What makes a duplicate: a question or its answers**
A user asks a question. A member proposes to use an approach different from what is asked. Do questions concerning the latter approach become duplicates? Well, may be the OP is totally wrong and the different a approach is necessary, but this does not seem the case here. In fact, there are other three answer that stay on the Start-Process approach and the OP solution itself is based on Start-Process. So *I cannot use these answers because are based on Start-Process, which is worthless in my case, but I can't start a new thread without Start-Process.*

**While this seems enough, there is also more**
Let us assume that the MSI question had been like: "Parameter  splatting to call an MSI installer". Would mine, in this case, be a duplicate? Not in my opinion.
In fact, a console call to a GUI installer does not works in the same way as a Docker call, and  this is not only because the former is a GUI app and the latter is a console app, but also because the latter involves several subtle Windows/Linux interoperability issues that do not matter with MSIs. PS paths do not work when passed as parameters to a Docker which uses Unix paths. Docker commands use themselves $-variables which can conflicy with PS variables. Docker allocates a pseudo-TTY, which can cause the PS call command to fail. Nothing like that  matters when calling an MSI (and the generality of native Windows commands), therefore Docker calls are in a league of their own.  A clear evidence of this difference is that the parameter splatting console solution working for the MSI call gives an error for the Docker call.

If I am wrong, as I might, please just tell me how I am supposed to apply the proposed [parameter-splatting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45225548/1851270) to a Docker call.

Comment: Duplication is so questions get to the right ANSWER. So it's all about "your answer may be there". I don't know enough to know if it's appropriate in your situation, but the answer is where the focus should be·

Comment: @Patrice: If Q' is a duplicate of Q,  that does not necessarily mean that (some) answers to Q are satisfactory. Unsatisfactory answers do not justify opening a new question. However, if A is a solution for Q and Q' is a duplicate, then A should be a solution for Q' too. I just try to  show that solutions for Q do not solve Q'. Hence Q and Q' differ.

Comment: Yes.... which is exactly what I say, so I don't understand why I am getting that comment back? I told you "it's all about your answer may be there". If you say it isn't, then I think it's pretty clear it isn't a dupe, no? I just don't know enough of the domain to be able to make that assertion myself.

Comment: @Patrice: Not at all, a critique to your point, just a clarification of mine... for those in a hurry.

Comment: I still don't fully see explained in your original question why you say *This works, but is inconvenient:* and later on *it doesn't work either.*. What is inconvenient and what didn't work?. The context you provide here in this meta has details that should go in to the question at hand.

Comment: @rene: Start-Process is perfect for an MSI installer where you need to see the popup and to control its level of visibility to understand that the silent installer is going. Instead, you don't want to start a new window each time you run a console app (and particularly in Docker where you interact back and forth with calling and called shell). To ["Run a command, script, or script block" PS specifically  provides `&`,  "the call operator, also known as the 'invocation operator'".](http://bit.ly/2CiebHI). Do you mean this should go in the question?

Comment: Yes, that  info should be in your question on main. You already missed [one opportunity](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/18714234) to get it re-opened. At least mention at the start that the MSI dupe can't be used in your case *because the awesome reasons you explained in your previous comment*. Ping me if you have made that edit.

Comment: @rene: [Amended post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599026/pass-powershell-variables-to-docker-commands).

Comment: I casted a re-open vote. Let's wait what the reviewers in the re-open queue make of it.

Comment: @rene: Question reopened. Now, sorry to bother you again, as I am relatively new to meta: (how) should I mark the case as solved? I mean since there is no answer to  "Accept".